# Web server not starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to implement [this tutorial](http://wesbos.com/html5-canvas-websockets-nodejs/).

The problem that i am facing is: 
I have downloaded `node.js` and run the command:`npm install socket.io`,  I get this message:[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Fw3rEXlvPTVEhfMFhQdk1FYkE/view?usp=sharing)
(sorry for the link to the drive but i don't yet have the required rep to post mages)
After that i have run the command `node server.js`

server.js:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.1
(function() {
  var io;

  io = require('socket.io').listen(4000);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {});

}).call(this);
```

which is running in cmd prompt but taking **forever**. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should run forever. It's how node.js works. This node process **is** your server. Your client application will connect to it via your port 4000.

Press Ctrl+C to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only porblem is that i don;t get the message 'Welcome to socket io ' which makes me think i have done something wrong..

Comment: There can me a thousand and one reasons to that. For examples: your firewall, or antivirus protection, or browser security restrictions, etc.